# open sms link from web app within uiwebview of 3rd party

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, sms, mailto

I have a mobile web app http://findkeeper.co and sometimes users enter it from being referred via Facebook post or message. So the user is coming in using Mobile Safari but within Facebook or Facebook Messenger.

Once on the page users are redirected to a mailto or sms to refer friends. However these no longer work.

I've tried a few ways, one is a simple SMS href link or mailto inside an  anchor tab, and also with angular $window or pure javascript window service.

Weird thing is that it used to work as of a few days ago, but has suddenly stopped working - I don't think anything changed.

All mailto and sms links on the following test pages fail when they from within Facebook Messenger or Facebook.

http://bradorego.com/test/sms.html

http://www.scottseverance.us/mailto.html

This is using iOS latest version.

Is this a messenger bug or is it just me. I swear this was working a few days ago.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a Facebook bug. I just tested on my phone and once I click on a link on the webview (living inside Messenger), I get a warning to confirm I want to leave the app. If I accept I am correctly sent to either Messages or Mail. So in order to determine what's going on I would try either running on another device, or checking that you haven't actually rejected the switch to the other apps.